# Maven install without internet connection

Tags: maven

I am trying to run the cmd maven compile install. I have mentioned my needed dependencies in the pom.xml. I know that it will get the needed jars from the local repository or central repository.

The problem is that I dont have internet connection (no connection to central repository). My question is - can I able to do the same with the system having internet connection and get all the required files in local repository by running maven compile install.

Then by copying the entire local repository (**.m2 folder**) from the networked system to the system without internet connection will make the maven compile install to succeed ? 
or any other solution is there ?

please help me out. Thanks

Comment: I test you opinion and i run the mvn clean compile without internet connection and its work ..... what's you must to is to get all what you need in your .M2 repository so i suggests you to go to cyber Coffey or same where when you can find connection execute your mvn compile and be sure that your pom.xml countaines all your dependencies and back to home

Comment: Thanks @mugiwaradz. It works, unless it needs an updated jar

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to install a repository manager run the build on one machine all the artifacts will be downloaded into the repository manager and from that time you can build that only with access to the repository manager.

An other solution would be to do as you described on one machine with internet access build your project and copy the local repository onto a second machine and run your build there via `mvn -o ...`.